# Django Getting QuerySet.values() based on condition

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model Class `Parent` and a Class `Child`. And child has a field called `status` and a `ForeignKey` relationship to `Parent`.

Let's say I retrieve one parent by calling filter (so as to have a QuerySet) by calling `p = Parent.objects.filter(pk=1)`

Now if I call `p.values('children__name')` I will receive a list of dictionaries of the children names to that parent.

My question is, if I wanted to call `p.values('children__name')` but limit the values only if the `status` of the child was specific, how would I do that?

I also want to make sure the original QuerySet is unaltered, as I don't want to filter it down (for larger QuerySets). I just want to filter the values that are based on some parameter. So for example, if I want to list all the parents and children that have a status of 'SICK' then I do not want to call `p.filter(children__status='SICK').values('children__name')` because that will filter the parents. I wish to still keep all the parents, just have the value of 'children__name' be filtered down to those with a specific status. Does that make sense?

Is there any way to do this in Django?

Comment: `p` will still contain all of the parents, or in this case 1 because you're strangely filtering on a primary key, if you filter it based on the status of a child being sick. If you don't assign the result to `p` then the original queryset won't be modified.

Comment: Yes my example only filtered for a primary key, but let's say I filtered for something else. Let's say `Parent.objects.filter(age=50)`. Now I want to not lose all the parents that are filtered there, yet only get the values based on that `sick` condition. Sorry for not really clarifying myself well.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = Parent.objects.filter(age=50)
sick_children = p.filter('children__status='sick').values('children__name')
```

The queryset will not be modified unless you assign the filter to `p`.

Comment: That is true, but `sick_children` will not have all parents included in `p` which is what I need. So in the end I would like a QuerySet such that it has all the parents in `p` but the values of `children__name` only if the status is `sick`. Is that possible?